# Updating AdHocWorkspace is slow

Tags: c#, .net, intellisense, roslyn

So I'm using Roslyn to generate intellisense results for a solution with many files, and I need to update the document every key press. Creating the sourcetext instance and the new solution takes very little time, but calling `workspace.TryApplyChanges` takes around 500ms per key press, which is too much for me. Am I doing this wrong? (I just want to generate completion results from the workspace through `CompletionService`. Here is how I'm updating my workspace:

```
SourceText sourceText = SourceText.From(editorText);
Solution newSolution = solutionDocument.Project.Solution.WithDocumentText(solutionDocument.Id, sourceText);
solutionWorkspace.TryApplyChanges(newSolution); //Every other part is pretty quick, except this.
solutionDocument = solutionWorkspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocument(solutionDocument.Id);
```

I am calling the above code EVERY single time the user types. Is there any way to make this quicker? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out. It turns out, all you have to do is just update your workspace like this:

```
solutionWorkspace.TryApplyChanges(solutionDocument.WithText(SourceText.From(editorText)).Project.Solution);
```

For some reason this is actually MUCH quicker!